# Show that a finite Galois extension has a finite number of intermediate fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

$Show$ that a finite Galois extension has a finite number of intermediate fields.

Comment: Your question needs more context. See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for tips. Also, this is a standard question. Search the site also.

Comment: In my book has only detailed  that.   I am sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be a finite galois extension of $F$. The intermediate fields are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $Gal(E/F)$ by the fundamental theorem. This group  has finite order and therefore finitely many subgroups as it has finitely many subsets so that the number of intermediate fields is finite.

Comment: I wouldn't say "by Lagrange's theorem". A finite group has finitely many subgroups for instance because it only has finitely many subsets

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much.